# Is the same Storyboard used per instance of control when defined in the UserControl's resources?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl defined something like the below:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SB">
      <ColorAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                      AutoReverse="True"
                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                      Duration="0:0:1"
                      To="Transparent"/>
    </Storyboard>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Border Background="{Binding StartColor}">
    <Border.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryBoard StoryBoard="{StaticResource SB}"/>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

When I create and display the first instance of the user control, the flashing works as expected, switching between **StartColor** and transparent.  However, each time I create another instance of the user control, the animation on all of the controls seems to get closer to being stuck on transparent until there is no flashing at all.

I did some searching and by changing the color animation to use **From** instead of **To**, it works as expected.  It also works if I leave the color animation as **To** but don't use a binding for the Border background and just set a color directly.

Is the color animation somehow shared between instances of the user control?  I do not understand how creating more instances of the user control can impact the animation on instances that have already been created or why changing to use **From** instead of **To** seems to fix it.  I would have expected each new instance that is created to start the animation from scratch, as if it is being run for the first time.

Comment: Try to set [`x:Shared="false"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xshared-attribute) for the `Storyboard`. _the default `x:Shared` condition for resources is `true`. This condition means that any given resource request always returns the same instance._

Comment: Or just don't use a resource at all, and declare the Storyboard inline.